# How to POST file with JSON:API in /jsonapi/file/file?

Tags: http-request

I tried with POSTMAN to upload a file to my endpoint host/jsonapi/file/file, the POST method is available but when I try to upload something, drupal gives me a 415 unsupported media type error. I tried with the binary option and with the data-form option using the next headers:

```
"Accept: application/vnd.api+json"
"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
'Content-Disposition: file; filename="test.jpg"'
```

The GET method works well. It returns me all the files.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you [check the docs](https://drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/file-uploads)?  Make sure that your user has permission to post files in the first place, too.

Comment: I found the way using the relationship field and the endpoint of that relationship, it can't be done directly to the jsonapi/file/file endpoint.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.  Feel free to post an answer to your own question; doing so is welcomed and encouraged here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a file I just change the endpoint "host/jsonapi/file/file" for "host/jsonapi/node/[my_specific_name]/[relationship_field_name]" with the binary option in the body of the POST in POSTMAN.

Also this documentation was really helpful [docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/3024331)